# How to run scanner in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, duplicates, java.util.scanner

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("1 - login");
    System.out.println("2 - regrister");

    int firstSelection = scanner.nextInt();

    while(firstSelection > 2 || firstSelection <1) {
        System.out.println(firstSelection+" is not a valid entry");
        int firstSelection = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("you picked "+firstSelection);
    }
```

**Issue:**

duplicate variable `firstSelection`

**What I'm trying to do:**

- ask user for an input
- When the while loop is ran. If the firstSelection is not a valid input I want to run the scanner again until they enter a valid response

**What I tried:**

```
    System.out.println("1 - login");
    System.out.println("2 - regrister");
    
    boolean fs;
    while((fs = scanner.nextInt() != 1) || (fs = scanner.nextInt() != 2)) {
        System.out.println(fs+" is not a valid entry");
    }
    System.out.println("you picked "+fs);
```

**Issue:**

- if i enter 1. I get no printline saying `you picked 1`. If i enter it again it tells me `true is not a valid entry`.
- if i enter a incorrect response it will continualy respond `true is not a valid entry`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int firstSelection;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("1 - login");
        System.out.println("2 - regrister");
        firstSelection = scanner.nextInt();
        if (firstSelection == 1 || firstSelection == 2)
            break;
        else {
            System.out.println(firstSelection + " is not a valid entry");
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("you picked " + firstSelection);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use the do-while loop  also

`do{

//your code here

}while(condition)`